# jQuery callback alerting twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Below code is alerting twice, plese explain -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("button").click(function() {
        $(".test").hide(300, function() {
            alert("hideen");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Are there two `.test` nodes?

Comment: Please provide related `html` code

Comment: Yep. so it it internally looping nodes with that class and hiding one by one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's just how `.hide()` works. From the [**documentation**](https://api.jquery.com/hide/):

> If multiple elements are animated, it is important to note that the callback is executed once per matched element, not once for the animation as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".test")` returns an array of elements with the class 'test'.

It's likely that you have two of these elements and therefore the callback is executed twice.

To verify that, try :

```
console.log($(".test").length);
```

If the output is '2', you got your answer.